# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_id, name})

Tags: javascript, reactjs

the error is in tbody and with map function.
code :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { getMovies } from "./services/fakeMovieService";

class MovieDatabase extends Component {
  state = {
    movies: getMovies(),
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Genre</th>
            <th>Stock</th>
            <th>Rate</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.state.movies.map((movie) => (
            <tr>
              <td>{movie.title}</td>
              <td>{movie.genre}</td>
              <td>{movie.numberInStock}</td>
              <td>{movie.dailyRentalRate}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }

  listStrecher() {}
}

export default MovieDatabase;
```

I was trying to iterate over a array of objects.Its is working fine when i return one  element. But showing me some errors when i try to return multiple elements.
Error :
(Error out put Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_id, name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.) 
check the below cases:

```
//Working fine
<tr>
    <td>{movie.title}</td>
</tr>

//Not working(showing Error)
<tr>
    <td>{movie.title}</td>
    <td>{movie.genre}</td>
    <td>{movie.numberInStock}</td>
    <td>{movie.dailyRentalRate}</td>
</tr>
```

The list which i was trying to iterate

```
const movies = [
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471815",
    title: "Terminator",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471818", name: "Action" },
    numberInStock: 6,
    dailyRentalRate: 2.5,
    publishDate: "2018-01-03T19:04:28.809Z"
  },
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471816",
    title: "Die Hard",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471818", name: "Action" },
    numberInStock: 5,
    dailyRentalRate: 2.5
  },
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471817",
    title: "Get Out",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471820", name: "Thriller" },
    numberInStock: 8,
    dailyRentalRate: 3.5
  },
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471819",
    title: "Trip to Italy",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471814", name: "Comedy" },
    numberInStock: 7,
    dailyRentalRate: 3.5
  },
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd47181a",
    title: "Airplane",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471814", name: "Comedy" },
    numberInStock: 7,
    dailyRentalRate: 3.5
  },
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd47181b",
    title: "Wedding Crashers",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471814", name: "Comedy" },
    numberInStock: 7,
    dailyRentalRate: 3.5
  },
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd47181e",
    title: "Gone Girl",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471820", name: "Thriller" },
    numberInStock: 7,
    dailyRentalRate: 4.5
  },
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd47181f",
    title: "The Sixth Sense",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471820", name: "Thriller" },
    numberInStock: 4,
    dailyRentalRate: 3.5
  },
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471821",
    title: "The Avengers",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471818", name: "Action" },
    numberInStock: 7,
    dailyRentalRate: 3.5
  }
];

export function getMovies() {
  return movies;
}
```

Comment: Can you mark my answer as accepted if it helped you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting the `genre.name`

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { getMovies } from "./services/fakeMovieService";

class MovieDatabase extends Component {
  state = {
    movies: getMovies(),
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Genre</th>
            <th>Stock</th>
            <th>Rate</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.state.movies.map((movie) => (
            <tr>
              <td>{movie.title}</td>
              {/*Get the name of the genre here*/}
              <td>{movie.genre.name}</td>
              <td>{movie.numberInStock}</td>
              <td>{movie.dailyRentalRate}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }

  listStrecher() {}
}

export default MovieDatabase;
```

Comment: Oh yeah, that's a crazy mistake. Thanks :)

Comment: yh it happens )

Answer (score 2):

`movie.genre` returns an object. As the error says, you can't do that in React. Just select the required info from `genre` object and render only that like `movie.genre.name`.